# Python/Numpy array element assignment issue

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to use Python/Numpy for a project that I'd normally do in Matlab, so I'm somewhat new to this environment (though I have played with Python/Django on the web development side). I'm now running into what I have to believe is a super simple issue that occurs when I'm trying to assign an element of a numpy array to another numpy array. The basic offending code is as follows.  It does have some other fluff around it which I don't believe could be causing the issue, but I can provide that code as well if it would help.

```
import numpy as np
tf = 100
dt = 10
X0 = np.array([6978,0,5.8787,5.8787])
xhist = np.zeros(tf/dt+1)
yhist = np.zeros(tf/dt+1)
xhist[0] = X0[0]
yhist[0] = X0[1]

print(X0[0])
print(xhist[0])
```

When I run the above code, the first print statement gives me 6978, as expected; however, the second print statement gives me 0, and I can't figure out for the life of me why this is. Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: both statements give to me `6978.0` which version of python and numpy are you using?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.4.3 and numpy 1.8.2.  I also confirmed the issue once on [link](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/try-ipython/), though as soon as I printed xhist, the problem disappeared for the next time I tried running the code.  Very mysterious.  I'm in the process of putting ipython on my Windows machine and will report back soon.

Comment: I have python `3.4.3` and numpy `1.10.1`.  With you code they are should be the same..

Comment: Interesting.  I just put only the above lines into a test file (thus removing the fluff I mentioned earlier) and I still see the same issue.  I'm mystified.  I'm doing this on Linux now, and Anaconda is still installing on Windows, so we'll see if I can replicate the issue there.

Comment: Problem solved!  I was using a trick I do all the time in Matlab to save typing, so instead of `yhist = np.zeros(tf/dt+1)` I actually had `yhist = xhist`.  This does very different things in Python, and I should have remembered that.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: To assign a copy of `xhist` to `yhist` (rather than a reference) you could use `yhist = xhist.copy()`